# How to integrate webform into multi form wizard into drupal 7

Tags: webforms, chaos-tool-suite, forms

I am trying to integrate webform into multiform wizard in drupal 7. but its not working, i dont have any idea how to integer it. if it is not possible to integrate awebform into multiform wizard then is there any alternate solution to do the same like wizard format.

Comment: i dont want to create multi steps by webform. i am creating my own multi form wizard in that i want to integer webform. like 1st step is registration(where we can fill some details) and 2nd step is webform(where we can create a webform by drag and drop) and 3rd step is some other form..

Answer (score 0):

You could set the redirection path of the webform to your new form upon completion. By default it stays on the node page.

Comment: how do i display webform into CTOOLS MULTISTEP WIZARD.